# Allowing Duplicates in a Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm looking to send a transactional email to a list of clients who have purchased several products from my company. I need to send them an email with the serial numbers. But every time I upload the lists it removes the duplicates. How do I allow a data extension to have duplicates and to send the user multiple emails. The information within the email will have different content because each one has a different serial number.

Thanks for any and all help!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing to do is set all of the data extension columns to nullable and do an overwrite action on the import.

On your send definition, you'll need to make sure you have the "de-duplicate by email address" checkbox *unchecked*.

Comment: Thanks! That helped a lot. However, I should have added that I need to have this as an option in Journey Builder. After doing some research it seems as though this feature doesn't exist within Journey Builder. Is that correct? If so, do you know of a work around?

Comment: Hey Adam, please slow down on the edits. You're flooding the home page really hard. :)

Comment: Gotcha.  Didn't realize there was such a disparity in the tagging.

Comment: Do you need me to create a tag synonym or something?

Comment: I suppose it's up for debate. I think ampscript posts should have marketing-cloud tags and ampscript references should have ampscript tags. I generally fix them when I interact, but it seems there's a lot of posts that don't follow that pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of the following Solution when it comes to Journey Builder.

1. Have the Journey Settings as 'Re-entry anytime'
2. Have a composite Primary key in your data extension which is Marking the Emailaddress field or Subscriber key field as primary field and also mark orderID field as the primary key or anything that is similar to that.

Thanks!